# Datapoint style in Silverlight Chart Series(ColumnSeries/BarSeries/LineSeries)

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I have a very wierd issue with style of Silverlight Charting controls. When I create a DataPointStyle for anyseries It ignore the existing default color combination. It starts showing me same(orange) color for everything even I haven't set anything in the background of DataPointStyle.

What I want is to create some custom tooltip and leave the background as it is. But its not working for me. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Vinod

Comment: Do any of the suggestions posted on http://forums.silverlight.net/t/142804.aspx/1 help?

Comment: I went through the link but didn't help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick is not to apply the data-point style to the chart itself, but rather to the individual colours that make up the palette.

I started with the following, which uses a PieChart.  The same principles should apply when using other types of chart:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChartPaletteDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="pointStyle" TargetType="toolkit:DataPoint">
            <Setter Property="DependentValueStringFormat"
                    Value="The value is {0:N0}" />
            <Setter Property="RatioStringFormat" Value="" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <toolkit:Chart>
        <toolkit:Chart.Series>
            <toolkit:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}"
                               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                               DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                               DataPointStyle="{StaticResource pointStyle}" />
        </toolkit:Chart.Series>
    </toolkit:Chart>
</UserControl>
```

This gave me a pie chart with the customised tooltip text but with all segments orange.

The next step is to set a custom palette.  A palette used by the Silverlight Toolkit charts is a `ResourceDictionaryCollection`, with each contained `ResourceDictionary` representing a colour within the palette.  You can find the 'default' palette for the chart within `Themes\generic.xaml` in the assembly `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`.  You can use a tool such as Blend or ILSpy to get at this palette.

I took this 'default' palette, and:

- removed all of the setters for the `DataShapeStyle` (I'm not sure they're necessary, but you can keep them if you wish),
- changed the `TargetType` of each `DataPointStyle` from `Control` to `toolkit:DataPoint`, and
- added `BasedOn="{StaticResource pointStyle}"` to each `DataPointStyle`.

This last point is what sets up the custom tooltip format with each palette entry.

This left me with something like the following, which I added to `<UserControl.Resources>`:

```
    <toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="chartPalette">
        <!-- Blue -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Background" GradientOrigin="-0.1,-0.1"
                                 Center="0.075,0.015" RadiusX="1.05"
                                 RadiusY="0.9">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB9D6F7" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF284B70" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="toolkit:DataPoint"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource pointStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- other styles copied similarly, but omitted for brevity -->
   </toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
```

I then removed `DataPointStyle="{StaticResource pointStyle}"` from the `PieSeries` and added `Palette="{StaticResource chartPalette}"` to the `<toolkit:Chart>` element instead.  When I ran the application I got the four segments of the pie to use different colours.

Acknowledgement: most of this has been taken from atomlinson's post on the Silverlight forums at  http://forums.silverlight.net/post/330170.aspx.

Comment: thanks buddy but it is quite wierd if I have 4 type of chart I will have to write 4 style for each chart.Anyway withouth have a property solution yours is quite impressive for me. Cheers! Vindo